# Lettuce client configuration to connect to aws redis elasticache

Tags: amazon-web-services, client, amazon-elasticache, lettuce

I have aws redis elastic cache configured in cluster mode enabled and I have one primary and one replica (both in separate availability zones). I am using Spring RedisTemplate along with LettuceClientConfiguration but getting below error when I try to write into redis:-

[http-nio-8080-exec-5] ERROR c.a.w.c.auth.Login - Authentication failed: Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: MOVED 15226 xxxx-redis-0001-002.xxx-redis.xxxx.xxxx.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
org.springframework.data.redis.RedisSystemException: Error in execution; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisCommandExecutionException: MOVED 15226 xxxx-redis-0001-002.xxx-redis.xxxx.xxxx.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:54)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:52)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceExceptionConverter.convert(LettuceExceptionConverter.java:41)
at org.springframework.data.redis.PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(PassThroughExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:44)
at org.springframework.data.redis.FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.translate(FallbackExceptionTranslationStrategy.java:42)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnection.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceConnection.java:268)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceHashCommands.convertLettuceAccessException(LettuceHashCommands.java:471)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceHashCommands.hGet(LettuceHashCommands.java:172)
at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.DefaultedRedisConnection.hGet(DefaultedRedisConnection.java:926)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultHashOperations.lambda$get$0(DefaultHashOperations.java:53)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:224)
at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:184)

I am using aws redis configuration endpoint url to connect to redis through spring and  I provide the host name through properties file:-

@Configuration
public class RedisCacheConfig {

```
private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RedisCacheConfig.class);

@Value("${redishost:localhost}")
private String host;

@Value("${redisport:6379}")
private int port;

@Value("${redisauth:}")
private String redisauth;

@Bean
public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {
    RedisStandaloneConfiguration conf = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(host, port);
    if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(redisauth)) {
        logger.info("Setting redis auth");
        conf.setPassword(redisauth);
        LettuceClientConfiguration clientConf = LettuceClientConfiguration.builder().useSsl().disablePeerVerification().build();
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(conf, clientConf);
    } else {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(conf);
    }
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, ?> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, ?> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
    return template;
}

@Bean
public CacheService getService() {
    return new RedisCacheService();
}
```

}

I believe lettuce is auto discovering the cluster and trying to write to replica node.

Can someone help me how should I integrate with aws redis using lettuce client?

Answer (score 0):

you are using RedisStandaloneConfiguration which tells Lettuce to try run redis in a single mode instead of a cluster one . For cluster mode you should be using RedisClusterConfiguration something like this -> new RedisClusterConfiguration(Arrays.asList(host+port))